# flask-sqlalchemy write huge file to database

Tags: python, mysql, flask-sqlalchemy, large-file-upload

I am trying to load a huge file like 5900 lines of sql creates, inserts and alter tables into mysql database with flask-SQLalchemy.

I am parsing the file and seperate each command by splitting between ;

This works as expected.

[Here](https://gist.github.com/marcelh89/81b0758563f0e585d37a) is what I am having so far.

For the SQL Query execution I am using the Engine API of SQLAlchemy.

When I execute the queries it seems that the database quits its job after like 5400lines of the file, but the application logs the full execution until line 5900 without error.

When i do the creates and inserts seperately it also works, so is there a way to split the batch execution or use pooling or something like that, which does not make the database stuck.

Thank you!

Comment: Is there any particular reason why you are loading an SQL dump via SQL Alchemy? Why not do it with terminal SQL server commands? Then, you wouldn't even have to parse.

Comment: I have to parse it because i need to modify the tablenames as I use a special mapping like <USER>_<TABLENAME>. But after that the query execution may work like that. I'll test it out.